# How to solve 'ascp: "user@host:" in all sources must match' when download SRA data with linux?

Tags: linux, sequence

I'm running the command `-ascp -v -i ~/.aspera/connect/etc/asperaweb_id_dsa.openssh -k 1 -T -l200m anonftp@ftp-private.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov:/sra/sra-instant/reads/ByRun/sra/SRR/SRR590/SRR5907429 /SRR5907429 .sra ~/sra_download` with Linux 
and I get this error -

```
"user@host:" in all sources must match
```

What does this mean?How to solve it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you research?

Answer (score 0):

First,"-private"should be removed.Secondly,need to correct the space error in the sentence，example "SRR5907429  ".'ascp -v -i ~/.aspera/connect/etc/asperaweb_id_dsa.openssh -k 1 -T -l200m anonftp@ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov:/sra/sra-instant/reads/ByRun/sra/SRR/SRR590/SRR5907429/SRR5907429.sra ~/sra_download'is the correct answer we need.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcKOS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem:
the ascp syntax is:

```
Usage: ascp [OPTION] SRC... DEST
          SRC to DEST, or multiple SRC to DEST dir
          SRC, DEST format: [[user@]host:]PATH
Display full usage: -h,--help
```

You get this by simply executing ascp, get more with "ascp -h" and have a manual for it as well, or https://download.asperasoft.com/download/docs/entsrv/3.9.1/es_admin_linux/webhelp/index.html#dita/ascp_2.html

it is pretty much like "scp", but works also in "pull" mode.
so, you have:

options then one or multiple sources, then a single destination (always the last argument).

if the destination is: user@server:folder, then you do a push
if source is user@server:folder, then you do a pull

globally, you can only do a push or a pull at the same time. but there can be multiple sources, and always a single destination (on command line).

in you case you have:

- options: -v -i ~/.aspera/connect/etc/asperaweb_id_dsa.openssh -k 1 -T -l200m
- sources: anonftp@ftp-private.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov:/sra/sra-instant/reads/ByRun/sra/SRR/SRR590/SRR5907429 /SRR5907429 .sra
- destination:~/sra_download

the first source is: anonftp@ftp-private.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov:/sra/sra-instant/reads/ByRun/sra/SRR/SRR590/SRR5907429
the other sources are: /SRR5907429 .sra

so you specify one remote source, two local sources, and one local destination.

This is the error you get.

My advice:
do not use the legacy syntax, as you did, but instead, use the advanced syntax:

```
ascp [options] --mode=<send|recv> --user=<user> --host=<server> sources... destination
```

There are plenty of options, for instance, if all your source files are in the same folder, you can use: --source-prefix=

you can also use file list file (i.e. a file that contains the list of files you want to transfer, in case it is long and generated by a script) or even file par list file.

Note also, that there is an interesting front end for aspera command line transfers:

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/asperalm